# PostgresSql : error: syntax error at or near "?"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

when I try to run the below code , I get "error: syntax error at or near "?"". what
is this error and how can I get rid of this error?

```
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO appointments(from_date,meeting_completed,meeting_description,to_date,from_time,to_time,agenda) VALUES ?'
let post = {
    from_date: req.body.fromdate,
    meeting_completed: req.body.meetingcompleted,
    meeting_description: req.body.meetingdescription,
    to_date: req.body.todate,
    from_time: req.body.fromtime,
    to_time: req.body.totime,
    agenda: req.body.agenda,
}
var pool = new Pool({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    port: 5432,
    // idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
    // connectionTimeoutMillis: 0,
});

pool.query(sql, [post], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("ERROR", error)
    }
    res.status(201).send(`User added with ID`)
})
```

Comment: The syntax for `INSERT` is `INSERT INTO tab (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)`.

Comment: let sql = 'INSERT INTO appointments(appointment_number,from_date,meeting_description,to_date,from_time,to_time,agenda)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
    let post = {
        'appointment_number':'270',
        'from_date': req.body.fromdate,
        'meeting_description': req.body.meetingdescription,
        'to_date': req.body.todate,
        'from_time': req.body.fromtime,
        'to_time': req.body.totime,
        'agenda': req.body.agenda,
    }    this gives me syntax error at or near ","

Answer (score 0):

I admittedly don't know anything about node, but the proper formatting for your DML statement is:

```
INSERT INTO appointments
(from_date, meeting_completed, meeting_description,
 to_date, from_time, to_time, agenda)
VALUES
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Ignore the whitespace.  The point is that:

1. The actual values need to be enclosed in parentheses
2. Each parameter needs its own ? -- unless you are inserting literals or functions, there should be one parameter per field

Again, not nothing about node, alternately you can use named parameters:

```
INSERT INTO appointments
(from_date, meeting_completed, meeting_description,
 to_date, from_time, to_time, agenda)
VALUES
(:from_date, :completed, :description,
 :to_date, :from_time, :to_time, :agenda)
```

Comment: the error changes to error: syntax error at or near ","

Comment: Can you add the DDL for your table create?